# Error in docker-compose's mariadb when i restart it

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, unix-socket

I'm studying my project with this [github repository](https://github.com/lusehair/42inception).
Before start, my environment is Debian Linux. (i386)
If you want to launch yourself, please follow this process.

- clone this repository
- command `make` in root repository
- visit https://lusehair.42.fr . also visit https://lusehair.42.fr/wp-admin and change some posts.
  (password is in `42inception/srcs/.env`)
- `docker-compose down` in another terminal
  (you must in `42inception/srcs` folder)
- `sudo systemctl mariadb mysql nginx` (you can also do this with `service` command)
- if closing docker-compose is perfect, restart by `docker-compose up --build` or `make reload`.
- Maybe you could see errors... :(

I removed `log_error` option in config file, and checked error logs.
This is it.

```
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Aborting
mariadb_1    |
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
```

I searched about this error, and found some solutions about this.
But they didn't give me satisfied result.
How should I solve this?

Comment: Pls describe what you have tried already to spare us and yourself from suggesting a solution that did not work for you!

Comment: Well, no reaction, so close this with a duplicate suggesting you set the path to the socket file where your socket file is actually located.

Comment: @Shadow Sorry for late reaction... I have posted some more things from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207509/error-in-docker-composes-mariadb-when-i-restart-it Add my files, write what i tried. Thank you for your kind!