# Error in docker-compose's MariaDB when it is restarted

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, unix-socket

I'm studying my project with this [github repository](https://github.com/lusehair/42inception). Before start, my environment is Debian Linux (i386). If you want to launch yourself, please follow this process:

- clone this repository
- command `make` in root repository
- visit https://lusehair.42.fr . also visit https://lusehair.42.fr/wp-admin and change some posts.
  (password is in `42inception/srcs/.env`)
- `docker-compose down` in another terminal
  (you must in `42inception/srcs` folder)
- `sudo systemctl mariadb mysql nginx` (you can also do this with `service` command)
- if closing docker-compose is perfect, restart by `docker-compose up --build` or `make reload`.
- Maybe you could see errors...

I removed `log_error` option in config file, and checked error logs.
This is it:

```
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
mariadb_1    | 2021-06-30 10:03:24 0 [ERROR] Aborting
mariadb_1    |
srcs_mariadb_1 exited with code 1
```

Problem is that this project is working very well when I try it first.

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:inc
        volumes:
            - ~/data/maria:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MARIA_LOGIN: "${MARIA_LOGIN}"
            MARIA_PASS: "${MARIA_PASS}"
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        build:
            context: ./requirements/mariadb
            dockerfile: Dockerfile 
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        env_file: .env
               

    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        image: wordpress:inc
        volumes:
            - ~/data/wp:/var/www/wordpress
        restart: always
        environment:
            WP_LOGIN: "${WP_LOGIN}"
            WP_PASS: "${WP_PASS}"
            WPU_1LOGIN: "${WPU_1LOGIN}"
            WPU_1PASS: "${WPU_1PASS}"
            MARIA_LOGIN: "${MARIA_LOGIN}"
            MARIA_PASS: "${MARIA_PASS}"
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        build:
            context: ./requirements/wordpress
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        env_file: .env
    nginx:
        image: nginx:inc
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - wordpress
        ports:
             - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ~/data/wp:/var/www/wordpress
        build:
            context: ./requirements/nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
            vpcbr:
        extra_hosts:
            - "lusehair.42.fr:127.0.0.1"
        env_file: .env

networks:
    vpcbr:
        driver: bridge
```

```
#mariadb Dockerfile

FROM debian:buster 

MAINTAINER lusehair <lusehair@42.student.fr>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server vim procps; 

COPY tools/setup.sh . 
RUN chmod +x setup.sh 

EXPOSE 3306
RUN rm /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf 
# Swith off the bind address 
COPY tools/50-server.cnf /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d 
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/setup.sh"]
```

```
#mariadb setup.sh

if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mysql/wordpress" ]; then 
    
    mysql_install_db
    service mysql start
    
    mysql -e "CREATE USER '${MARIA_LOGIN}'@'localhost' identified by '${MARIA_PASS}';" &&\
    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wordpress;" &&\
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${MARIA_LOGIN}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MARIA_PASS}';" &&\
    mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    service mysql stop 
fi
#sleep 5
mysqld
```

```
# mariadb 50-server.cnf

# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port                   = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
#key_buffer_size        = 16M
#max_allowed_packet     = 16M
#thread_stack           = 192K
#thread_cache_size      = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
#myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
#query_cache_limit      = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time        = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = exclude_database_name

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
#chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
#ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
#ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
#ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
#ssl-cipher = TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
#ssl = on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.3 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.3]
```

Things I tried:

- remove `log_error` from `50-server.cnf` to check error
- change `socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to `socket = /run/mysqld/mysql.sock` (i saw this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/420285/error-running-mysql-daemon))
  Q. someone says mysqld.sock is in `/var/lib/mysql/`, one other says `/tmp/` but my thing is `/run/mysqld/`. What is right thing?
- try to change structure of `setup.sh`. the project worked when first try, so I thought there is a problem of restarting something, and tried some things. (make directory, ln -s mysqld file, etc) but none of them worked.

I think problem is caused in `setup.sh` or `50-server.cnf`. But I don't know exactly about structure of these. I couldn't find answer.

Comment: Expanded duplicate of your prior question: [Error in docker-compose's mariadb when i restart it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206033/error-in-docker-composes-mariadb-when-i-restart-it)

Comment: Please, edit your original question, do not post a new one. Happy to reopen the original, if the duplicate there did not help. Pls note, you are the only one who knows where your socket file is located in your file system. If you do not know where it is, you need to find it.

Comment: The stackoverflow told me to write a new one. @Shadow @halfer
```Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.
Closed 1 hour ago.
(Private feedback for you)```